# React change state

Tags: reactjs

I have an array in the state and want to change the array depending on the index here is the method I use

```
dynamicFieldsOnChange(e, index) {
    this.setState({[product_colors[index]]: e.target.value});
};
```

But it's not working any idea why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

Comment: https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b

Comment: @flppv and what about the first question it's not duplicated, why is `[[e.target.id][index]]` not working?

Comment: @SimpleWebDesigner your code isn't complete to answer that. What is `index` ?

Comment: @flppv an index for array...

Answer (score 0):

Directly updating state value using

```
this.state[e.target.id] = e.target.value
```

is a bad practice. You should always avoid that.

Instead, you should do something like this,

```
this.setState({[e.target.id] : e.target.value});
```

This will set id in a local state.

Comment: `this.setState = {[e.target.id] : e.target.value}` does not work.

Comment: I need it with `[index]` please that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the previous state first, using prevstate callback event. if you want to retain all the elements of an array . spread the prevState . then call the product_colors then pass the modified array.

Like this:

```
  dynamicFieldsOnChange(e,index)
  {
    this.setState( (prevState) => {
      prevState.product_colors[index] = e.target.value
      return{
        ...prevState,
        product_colors: [...prevState.product_colors]
      }
      });
  };
```

Comment: can you you give me the initial and final output of the state? to know what s the problem?

Comment: here is the array for example `product_colors: (2) ["white", "New Entry 1"]` I want to change `"New Entry 1"`, so I used `index` (which in this case equals 1) to change the entry

Comment: I mean , what is the output and input of state, on implementing of the code above that i suggested.

Comment: error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: your error here must be e.target.value, does not exist in the first place. check the e property in console log to get the proper address of the value you wanna get.

try to make e.value.target to static value like.  prevState.product_colors[index] = 'Change' to know that the logic is working